# Django index value of array

Tags: django, ajax, django-views

I am sending an array of arrays a post request through $ajax

ie:
`[[1, "25, 25, 25", "pounds", "exercise note 1"],[2, "", "No Weight", "note 2"]]`

My ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:{
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
                    targets:JSON.stringify(targets),
                    // notes:notes,
                    // time:time,
                    // rating:rating
                },
                success: (res)=>{
                    console.log(res)
                },
                error: (error)=>{
                    console.log(error)
                }
            })
```

In django, when I `print(request.POST)`, I get
`'targets[0][]':[1, "25, 25, 25", "pounds", "exercise note 1"], 'target[1][0]':[2, "", "No Weight", "note 2"]`.

I have tried

`JSON.stringify([[1, "25, 25, 25", "pounds", "exercise note 1"],[2, "", "No Weight", "note 2"]])`
and I get back

`'targets': ['[[2,"25, 25, 25","Pounds","note 1"],[1,"","NoWeights","note 2"]]']`,

I've also tried:

```
ts.push(t)
```

django returns:

```
'targets[]': ['[2,"25, 25, 25","Pounds","note 1"]', '[1,"","NoWeights","note 2"]
```

which is what I want. But when I do

```
targets = request.POST.getlist('targets[])
for target in targets: 
    print(target[2]) -->I want either "25, 25, 25" or , ""
```

But all I get is , and when I `print(len(target))` the first array returns 34. Why? How do I get the strings? What am I doing wrong? I want to assigned each index in the target array to a varible so I can save to the database

Answer (score 0):

If you send targets as JSON in your request(NOTE: only the targets part is JSON) then you have to decode it when you get it on the server side.

```
targets = [[1, "25, 25, 25", "pounds", "exercise note 1"],[2, "", "No Weight", "note 2"]];
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:{
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
        targets:JSON.stringify(targets),
        // notes:notes,
        // time:time,
        // rating:rating
        },
        success: (res)=>{
            console.log(res)
        },
        error: (error)=>{
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
});
```

```
targets_json = request.POST.get('targets')
targets = json.loads(targets_json)
for target in targets: 
    print(target[2])
```

Comment: OMG!! That did!! I had stayed up till 2 last night, trying to get it to workout!! For future googlers reading this, I did have to ```import json``!